# Django Model's Return Value

Tags: python, django

i have a model:

```
class student(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    STNO = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
```

However in my program and admin panel i see "Student Object" instead of name, id, etc

i tried following codes but still not working

```
def __str__(self):
     return self.First_Name

def __str__(self):
     return "{0} {1}".format(self.First_Name, self.Last_Name)
```

Comment: shouldn't class name student be in uppercase and field names in lower-case it a general convention.

Comment: in case you are using python 2, you need to define `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`

Comment: what ??? :| if one is Uppercase and other one is lower-case program didn't work @PrashantShukla

Comment: Its not really an answer, but in the link to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str) I suggested in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34351457/1324033), You could also just decorate your class with `@python_2_unicode_compatible`. (Also, try setting the `__repr__` method instead/as well as the `__str__` method)

Comment: thank you very much @Sayse ... i see that doc and also try using "python_2_unicode_compatible" but still i have that problem

Comment: i have python 3.5 installed @Sayse

Comment: you should look over here once https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id29 their is no harm in naming fields in upper-case but you can't name a class in lower-case PEP-008

Comment: As far as Unicode problem is concern usually it works but if you're still facing same problem use from **django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode** and **return smart_unicode(self.name)**

Comment: ok .... i fix PEP0008 Coding standards ... but still not working @PrashantShukla

Comment: Ok so when you access your admin your app is showing Student right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for your helpful answers

i tried following ways and finally find the answer :

1- fix PEP0008 Coding Standards

2- change **STR** to **str**

3- Remove database and create new one

4- Restart server

also i tried "**unicode**" - "**repr**" - "**smart_unicode**" but i think the orginal **str** is the best thing for the examples like this

Answer (score 5):

I think you are using `Python 2x` so you should try `__unicode__`

```
class Student(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   stno = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return "{0} {1}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

By the way, field names should be all lowercase, using underscores instead of camelCase.

And class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Comment: thank you but still i have problem

Comment: @ArashHatami should be work. What is your exception?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code to this one:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    stno = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
      return self.first_name
```

Then you have to make changes on database: `python manage.py migrate`, `python manage.py makemigration` and restart server. Hope it helps

Comment: why should i change class name to upper-case ??? and names to lower-case

Comment: Its a Pep8 coding standard, its not necessary, its just what the majority of all python code you find will be using.

Comment: thank you for information but i have a big program with many lines of code .... if i change one of them Later I was in trouble.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Comment: ok .... i fix PEP0008 Coding standards ... but still not working

Comment: did you restart your server?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to define the **unicode** function. Also, this is not really a save way to do this, if first_name and last_name can be null.
My suggestion would be:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   fast_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
   stno = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
      first_name = self.first_name if self.first_name else u'John'
      last_name = self.last_name if self.last_name else u'Doe'
      return first_name + ' ' + last_name
```

Comment: "def __unicode__(self)" out of class ?

Comment: sorry, jsut updated my answer

Comment: no ..... doesn't work

Comment: it should though ;). Did you restart your server? Deleted *.pyc files?

Comment: yes !! i don't know the answer ..... i tried many ways

Comment: Did you try to debug into the __unicode__ function if it even jumps into that one?

Comment: If you are using Pycharm (which I would recommend) you can just put a breakpoint there and start the debugger

Comment: no @remi ... i just use notepad++ for editing .py files

Comment: well then just put a print or logging statement in your function and see if it pops up in console